# how to filter in with a comparition between 2 fields

Tags: angularjs, ng-filter

I want filter `servers` on the condition for those records with `serverState` and the `initialstate` in them are not equal.

```
{{servers | filter : serverState != initialState}}
```

Comment: Can you provide some demo data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own custom filter which has logic to filter the server  which don't have initial state matching with initalState variable value.

Your Custom filter

```
myApp.filter('filterServer', function () {
  return function (servers,initialState) {
  var filteredArray=[];
  for (var k = 0; k < servers.length; ++k) {
    var server = servers[k];
    if (server.state != initialState) filteredArray.push(server);
    }
    return filteredArray;
  };
});
```

Your HTML

```
<tr ng-repeat="server in Servers | filterServer : initialState">
      <td style="width:50%;fload:left">
          <span ng-bind="server.server"></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width:40%;fload:left">
         <span ng-show="server.state==1">State 1</span>
         <span ng-show="server.state==2">State 2</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

For sample please check this link

http://fiddle.jshell.net/zxr0qa1k/5/

Comment: thanks a lot, was just wondering if there was any way to do it without a custom filter?

Comment: You can do it but need data manipulation.  If you want to go with serverState != initialState condition this will return bool value and try to apply filter on returned bool value. If you introduce one more bool property to your array and try to filter on that property.